# Group By key Meteor Collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections, group-by

Hello I've searched a lot before asking the question and still have not found any decent answer to my question.
I have a collection (it's copying from MSSQL table every x second) like this: https://ekhmoi.tinytake.com/sf/MzU2MTcwXzIwNDcxNTg

As you can see there are fields which has the same key (MessageId).
My goal is some kind of grouping them, by taking MessageId + Message(of each record which has the same MessageId) and finally i will insert it to new Collection.
so final result should look like this:
https://ekhmoi.tinytake.com/sf/MzU2MTc3XzIwNDcyMDY

Any idea how can i do this ?

Comment: Have you tried using mongodb's aggregation framework? You can use it in meteor by adding `meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate` package which will allow you to use .aggregate on collection instances.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use this framework in my case

Comment: In your final result, would you mind if all the messages are in an array instead of message_1, message_2, message_3.....?

Comment: Please give an example to try. Anything to move from the point I've stucked should be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation for grouping your collection data to get your final result and the process is actually very simple.

First of all run `meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate` and `meteor add mikowals:batch-insert` if you have not yet added these two packages.

Assuming CollectionA is the first collection and CollectionB is the second collection. Here is how I would group data from Collection A and write the final result in CollectionB:

```
let pipeline = [
    {$project: {TraceId: 1, MessageId: 1, Message: 1}},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$MessageId",
        Message: {$push: "$Message"},
        TraceId: {$first: "$TraceId"}
    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: 0,
        MessageId: "$_id",
        Message: 1,
        TraceId: 1
    }}
];

let groupedData = CollectionA.aggregate(pipeline);

CollectionB.batchInsert(groupedData);
```

Note that this example is just the representation of my idea so it may be not working if you copy paste directly to your code.